Having trouble proving Taylor Expansion
In the book Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu, the author introduces a method for obtaining the Taylor expansion on "star-shaped" (i.e., any line segment connecting points in the set to a special point lies entirely within the set) open sets in Euclidean space for $C^{\infty}$ functions. The precise lemma is stated as follows:

Let $f$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function on an open subset $U$ of
$\mathbb{R}^n$ that is star-shaped with respect to a point
$p = (p^1, \dots, p^n)$ in $U$. Then there exist functions
$g_1(x), \dots, g_n(x) \in C^{\infty}(U)$ such that
$$f(x) = f(p) + \sum_{i=1}^n (x^i - p^i) g_i(x), \quad g_i(p) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p).$$

Using the Newton-Leibniz formula, this can be proved as follows:
$$\begin{align}
f(x) - f(p) &= \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} f\left(p + t(x - p)\right) \mathrm{d}t \\[2ex]
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (x^i - p^i) \int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p + t(x - p)) \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align}$$
Let
$$g_i(x) := \int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p + t(x - p)) \mathrm{d}t.$$

I want to use this lemma to derive the Taylor expansion. Repeated application of this lemma leads to
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= f(p) + \sum_{i=1}^n (x^i - p^i) \left( g_i(0) + \sum_{j=1}^n (x^j - p^j) g_{ij}(x) \right) \\[2ex]
& \cdots \\[2ex]
&= f(p) + \sum_{i=1}^n (x^i - p^i) g_i(p) + \sum_{i,j=1}^n (x^i - p^i) (x^j - p^j) g_{ij}(p) + \cdots + \text{remainder},
\end{align}$$
where $g_i(x) = g_i(p) + \sum_{j=1}^n(x^j - p^j) g_{ij}(x)$ follows from the lemma. However, I encountered a problem with the factorial denominators that appeared when calculating the coefficient $g_{ij}(p)$. Note that:
$$\begin{align}
g_{ij}(x) &= \int_0^1 \frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x^j}(p + s(x - p)) \mathrm{d}s,
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x^j}(x) &= \int_0^1 \sum_{\ell=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^\ell \partial x^j}(p + t(x - p)) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}(p^\ell + t(x^\ell - p^\ell)) \mathrm{d}t \\[2ex]
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^j \partial x^i}(p + t(x - p)) t \mathrm{d}t,
\end{align}$$
thus
$$g_{ij}(x) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^j \partial x^i}(p + st(x - p)) t \mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d}s.$$
Hence, we get:
$$g_{ij}(p) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{2!} \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial {x^i}^2}(p), & \text{if} ~i=j \\[2ex]
\dfrac{1}{2!} \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^j \partial x^i}(p), & \text{if} ~i \ne j
\end{cases},$$
but the actual result is:
$$g_{ij}(p) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{2!} \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial (x^i)^2}(p), & \text{if} ~i=j \\[2ex]
\dfrac{1}{1!1!} \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^j \partial x^i}(p), & \text{if} ~i \ne j
\end{cases}.$$
So where did I go wrong in my derivation process? Can somebody help me? Thanks.

I wonder if it should be $g_i(p) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p)$ in the lemma.

It suffices to prove it in 1-D because you can apply the 1-D version to $\phi(t) = f(p + t(x - p))$

@MartinR yes, you are right, it’s just a typo, I’ve corrected it, thanks.

@Kakashi but $g_i$ are still $C^\infty$ function from $U$ to $\mathbb R$, why can’t I apply the lemma again?

Try plugging in a specific simple function like $f(x^1,x^2) = (x^1)^4 (x^2)^3$ and see what's the first line that's incorrect.

@aschepler Oh, I see. I forgot to merge similar terms, such as: $$f(x)=\text{Taylor terms}+(x^1)^2g_{11}(x)+(x^1x^2g_{12}(x)+x^2x^1g_{21}(x))+(x^2)^2g_{22}(x).$$ Therefore, I need to multiply by some binomial coefficients to make it correct.
